# Keras access individual values in custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss

I want to achieve the following loss function:

- Receive a batch of dimension (batch_size, number_out_nodes)
- Apply a scipy function to each row/sample which maps it to a real number
- Combine the results of all samples from the batch

I already wrote the function using numpy arrays as input.

It looks something like this:

```
 def loss_func(y_true, y_pred):
      y_pred = np.array(y_pred)
      list_of_factors = [4]*len(y_pred)
      val = 0
      for idx, factor in list_of_factors:
          val += factor*scipy_func(y_pred[idx])
      return val
```

Is there any way to implement this function as Keras loss function? I do not know how to access the individual samples of the batch.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** apply any *scipy function* because the variables you get in the loss function are **tensors** and not nD NumPy arrays. So no NumPy or SciPy inside the loss function that take tensors as arguments.

Depending on what your *scipy function* is, you might be able to implement it using operations available in the [Keras backend](https://keras.io/backend/). Most of the functions are similar to NumPy operations but act on tensors.

Have a look at [existing loss functions](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py) and how they operate on tensors using those backend functions.

Comment: Thank you. But can I loop over the different samples in the batch like in a list/array (even if they are tensors)?

Comment: Yes, you can but often it is better to just perform vector operations rather than having any for loops at all.